# Android reutilizing Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities. A and B. A has a action bar with 4 items. Each item display  a different list of movies. B extends A cause I want to be able to use the action bar to change the movie list.

So my question is, can I use the same instance of activity (B) to show the different movie lists when I press an item in the action bar ?

```
 Activity B
```

[image: ACTIVITY B]

```
 Activity A
```

[image: ACTIVITY A]

Comment: So you want to only change the contents of the listview? if you dont care about navigation stack what is the problem? just replace your listview adapter.

Comment: So you want for  `ActivityA` to do nothing but to listen to on tab clicked to then call `ActivityB` to display the appropriate list in it. But what would happen if you click on a tab in `ActivityB`?

Comment: Activity A would be notified and it would get another type of list to be displayed by activity B

Comment: @Nanoc in the code i have right now that is not a viable option, is there a way to notify the intent to use the previous activity to display the list ?

Comment: That doesnt make sense you dont need an intent to notify your current activity, why it is not a viable option? best way is maybe using an interface.

Comment: What you are trying to do does not sound like the best solution. I think it is best if you could post your code so a better solution can be suggested to you. Also you could look at [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) for a more customised actionbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit over complicating it, you can use one activity `ActivityA` to have the *actions (tabs)* and the *list* (`Recyclerview`). When you click on a tab you update your *list* with the movies you want. Or you can create a `Fragment` to hold your movies list instead.

Also I suggest that you use *tabs* instead of *actionbar* actions they are more user friendly    and apply more to this case. If you go with the tabs you can have a `Viewpager` and you can swipe between your movie lists fragments. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging) is all you need for the tabbed view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override method click action bar buttons.

Where you click on "Popular" in **A**, you use your method:

```
public void clickPopular(){
    //some action for A
}
```

Where you click "Popular" in **B**, you use your  @Override method:

```
@Override
public void clickPopular(){
    //some action for B
}
```

Comment: No that is not what i need. The clicks to the action bar belong to A alone. Clicking in "Popular" will notify A to start a B activity with the list of popular films. What i want is to have some sort of flag that will use the SAME instance of B for all the movie lists available.

Comment: If you want use SAME instance of B ,use Intent flag:  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)